# git: automatic sync to remote for non-tech-savvies with GUI

Tags: git, sync, gui, cross-platform

Is there an easy GUI application for non-tech-savvies that enables automatic (i.e. on copy/create/delete file) syncing to a git remote.  It should be actively maintained, preferably cross-platform Windows/Linux (but if not then at least for Windows). Like [SparkleShare](https://www.sparkleshare.org/), just more actively maintained (especially it's Windows client).

Comment: I am sorry but using GIT for non-tech users is IMHO a bad idea. Git is that complex that it requires even for developers a long time to understand the basic commands. better use a tool like nextcloud/DropBox or similar for file transfer that is easier to understand for regular users.

Comment: We use git with SparkleShare over year now with non-tech users and it works great. They use it just for uploading files. But I can do advanced stuff if needs be. The only problem we face is that SparkleShare (for Windows) is not being maintained and bugs are not fixed. Otherwise the workflow is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

SourceTree by Atlassian (JIRA/Confluence/BitBucket): https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

Free comfort GUI app for Windows/Mac OS X and you can autorefresh git/hg repos.